# I want to change my linux distro, will this affect my data?

Tags: linux

I am using Debian right now but I would like to try another distro (maybe Ubuntu). Should I upload my files to somewhere (save them) or just changing distro will not delete my files?
Thank you!

Comment: Regular (daily or hourly) backups to some external storage is _always_ a good thing. You should do this even if you're not planning on reinstalling your system. See `restic` or `borgbackup`.

Comment: I have multipe Ubuntu flavors installed. I keep all data in a separate data partition and mount & link the folders in it into each install. That way I can experiment with changes and not worry about main working install having issues. But I also backup data partition & /home of main install. Does not have to be separate drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 2):

This is why I keep `/home` on a partition of its own, separate from the partition(s) containing system files.

This lets me update or even replace the OS, if I remember to tell the installer NOT to format `/home`.

Compatibility in the filesystem used for `/home`, in programs I've installed under `$HOME`, preservation of system settings, drivers, etc. is left as a problem for the student.

Answer (score 1):

Most distros do not have 'upgrade' options where they cleanly overwrite system files but keep your 'user' files. If you know where your own files are (i.e. /home/$user) and are able to back them up elsewhere, you should do this, then do a clean installation of a new distro. Your other option is to boot from a live CD (USB, etc) and test it out without changing anything on your hard drive. Changing the distro will delete your files. The only exceptions are version upgrades of some distros (i.e. Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking up **rsync**, because it is (at least, in  my opinion) the easiest and most-secure program to back up files. You can also set it to "mirror" your file structure, thus adding and removing files as necessary, to reflect how your /home/ directory currently looks.

I always plug in my USB external drive and run the command

`rsync -ravipP /home/(name)/ /media/external/backups/tyler/`

Works like a charm.